# Vaadin RouterLink highlight condition for parent layouts

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

I'm trying to implement correct highlight condition for route links in nested layouts.

I have the following page which has the following layout structure:

[image]

`1` - route link in `MainLayout`

`2` - route link in `CandidatesLayout`

`3` - route link in `CandidateLayout`

As you may see - `1` and `2` links are not highlighted but I need to highlight them also.

I added the following code to each route link:

```
    link.setHighlightCondition(buildHighLightConditionFor(navigationTarget));

    public static HighlightCondition<RouterLink> buildHighLightConditionFor(Class<?> linkTargetClass) {
        return (link, afterNavigationEvent) -> {
            return afterNavigationEvent
                    .getActiveChain()
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(element -> {
                        return element.getClass() == linkTargetClass;
                    });
        };
    }
```

I did this because I have a Route with `@RouteAlias("")` as described here https://cookbook.vaadin.com/highlight-link-with-default-route/about

How to extend this code in order to highlight `1` and `2` route links in parent layouts?

**UPDATED**

```
@Route(value = "candidates/:profileUuid", layout = CandidateLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
```

Comment: (3) is bold and that means highlighted? Might be easier to see/understand if you would pick some more obvious styling? What is the route of this images? `/candidates/$id/profile`?

Comment: yes, (3) is bold and this is what I mean highlighted. Vaadin adds additional style [highlighted] or something like that in this case. I added the view with the route in the question body right now. Thanks!